# Place order function in NopCommerce 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, nopcommerce

and I want to create a custom controller with a place order function.
I'm using the below code:

```
private async Task<Order> PlaceOrder(IList<ShoppingCartItem> cart)
    {
        var _orderProcessingService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IOrderProcessingService>();
        var _genericAttributeService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IGenericAttributeService>();
        var processPaymentRequest = HttpContext.Session.Get<ProcessPaymentRequest>("OrderPaymentInfo") ?? new ProcessPaymentRequest();

        _paymentService.GenerateOrderGuid(processPaymentRequest);
        processPaymentRequest.StoreId = (await _storeContext.GetCurrentStoreAsync()).Id;
        processPaymentRequest.CustomerId = (await _workContext.GetCurrentCustomerAsync()).Id;
        processPaymentRequest.PaymentMethodSystemName = await _genericAttributeService.GetAttributeAsync<string>(await _workContext.GetCurrentCustomerAsync(),
            NopCustomerDefaults.SelectedPaymentMethodAttribute, (await _storeContext.GetCurrentStoreAsync()).Id);
        HttpContext.Session.Set<ProcessPaymentRequest>("OrderPaymentInfo", processPaymentRequest);
        var placeOrderResult = await _orderProcessingService.PlaceOrderAsync(processPaymentRequest);
        if (placeOrderResult.Success)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Set<ProcessPaymentRequest>("OrderPaymentInfo", null);
            var postProcessPaymentRequest = new PostProcessPaymentRequest
            {
                Order = placeOrderResult.PlacedOrder
            };
            await _paymentService.PostProcessPaymentAsync(postProcessPaymentRequest);

            return postProcessPaymentRequest.Order;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But where can call the function to place an order and clear the cart?

I'm working on nopcommerce 4.5

Comment: why do you want to do this? As there is already a method PlaceOrderAsync and you also call it from your method.

Comment: @sina_Islam I'm working on a custom plugin. Could you explain the correct way to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can override checkout controller and action method for confirm order or simply override PlaceOrder method from OrderProcessingService and do you custom changes.

Answer (score 0):

As you are working on the custom plugin so the better way is to override the PlaceOrderAsync method.

Below is the code for override OrderProcessingService service from the plugin. I consider NivoSlider for example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nop.Core;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Common;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Customers;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Directory;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Discounts;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Localization;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Logging;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Orders;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Payments;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Shipping;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Tax;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Vendors;
using Nop.Core.Events;
using Nop.Services.Affiliates;
using Nop.Services.Catalog;
using Nop.Services.Common;
using Nop.Services.Customers;
using Nop.Services.Directory;
using Nop.Services.Discounts;
using Nop.Services.Localization;
using Nop.Services.Logging;
using Nop.Services.Messages;
using Nop.Services.Orders;
using Nop.Services.Payments;
using Nop.Services.Security;
using Nop.Services.Shipping;
using Nop.Services.Stores;
using Nop.Services.Tax;
using Nop.Services.Vendors;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Order processing service
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CustomOrderProcessingService : OrderProcessingService , IOrderProcessingService
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly CurrencySettings _currencySettings;
        private readonly IAddressService _addressService;
        private readonly IAffiliateService _affiliateService;
        private readonly ICheckoutAttributeFormatter _checkoutAttributeFormatter;
        private readonly ICountryService _countryService;
        private readonly ICurrencyService _currencyService;
        private readonly ICustomerActivityService _customerActivityService;
        private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;
        private readonly ICustomNumberFormatter _customNumberFormatter;
        private readonly IDiscountService _discountService;
        private readonly IEncryptionService _encryptionService;
        private readonly IEventPublisher _eventPublisher;
        private readonly IGenericAttributeService _genericAttributeService;
        private readonly IGiftCardService _giftCardService;
        private readonly ILanguageService _languageService;
        private readonly ILocalizationService _localizationService;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IOrderService _orderService;
        private readonly IOrderTotalCalculationService _orderTotalCalculationService;
        private readonly IPaymentPluginManager _paymentPluginManager;
        private readonly IPaymentService _paymentService;
        private readonly IPdfService _pdfService;
        private readonly IPriceCalculationService _priceCalculationService;
        private readonly IPriceFormatter _priceFormatter;
        private readonly IProductAttributeFormatter _productAttributeFormatter;
        private readonly IProductAttributeParser _productAttributeParser;
        private readonly IProductService _productService;
        private readonly IReturnRequestService _returnRequestService;
        private readonly IRewardPointService _rewardPointService;
        private readonly IShipmentService _shipmentService;
        private readonly IShippingService _shippingService;
        private readonly IShoppingCartService _shoppingCartService;
        private readonly IStateProvinceService _stateProvinceService;
        private readonly IStoreService _storeService;
        private readonly ITaxService _taxService;
        private readonly IVendorService _vendorService;
        private readonly IWebHelper _webHelper;
        private readonly IWorkContext _workContext;
        private readonly IWorkflowMessageService _workflowMessageService;
        private readonly LocalizationSettings _localizationSettings;
        private readonly OrderSettings _orderSettings;
        private readonly PaymentSettings _paymentSettings;
        private readonly RewardPointsSettings _rewardPointsSettings;
        private readonly ShippingSettings _shippingSettings;
        private readonly TaxSettings _taxSettings;

        #endregion

        #region Ctor

        public CustomOrderProcessingService(CurrencySettings currencySettings,
            IAddressService addressService,
            IAffiliateService affiliateService,
            ICheckoutAttributeFormatter checkoutAttributeFormatter,
            ICountryService countryService,
            ICurrencyService currencyService,
            ICustomerActivityService customerActivityService,
            ICustomerService customerService,
            ICustomNumberFormatter customNumberFormatter,
            IDiscountService discountService,
            IEncryptionService encryptionService,
            IEventPublisher eventPublisher,
            IGenericAttributeService genericAttributeService,
            IGiftCardService giftCardService,
            ILanguageService languageService,
            ILocalizationService localizationService,
            ILogger logger,
            IOrderService orderService,
            IOrderTotalCalculationService orderTotalCalculationService,
            IPaymentPluginManager paymentPluginManager,
            IPaymentService paymentService,
            IPdfService pdfService,
            IPriceCalculationService priceCalculationService,
            IPriceFormatter priceFormatter,
            IProductAttributeFormatter productAttributeFormatter,
            IProductAttributeParser productAttributeParser,
            IProductService productService,
            IReturnRequestService returnRequestService,
            IRewardPointService rewardPointService,
            IShipmentService shipmentService,
            IShippingService shippingService,
            IShoppingCartService shoppingCartService,
            IStateProvinceService stateProvinceService,
            IStoreService storeService,
            ITaxService taxService,
            IVendorService vendorService,
            IWebHelper webHelper,
            IWorkContext workContext,
            IWorkflowMessageService workflowMessageService,
            LocalizationSettings localizationSettings,
            OrderSettings orderSettings,
            PaymentSettings paymentSettings,
            RewardPointsSettings rewardPointsSettings,
            ShippingSettings shippingSettings,
            TaxSettings taxSettings) :base(currencySettings,
            addressService,
            affiliateService,
            checkoutAttributeFormatter,
            countryService,
            currencyService,
            customerActivityService,
            customerService,
            customNumberFormatter,
            discountService,
            encryptionService,
            eventPublisher,
            genericAttributeService,
            giftCardService,
            languageService,
            localizationService,
            logger,
            orderService,
            orderTotalCalculationService,
            paymentPluginManager,
            paymentService,
            pdfService,
            priceCalculationService,
            priceFormatter,
            productAttributeFormatter,
            productAttributeParser,
            productService,
            returnRequestService,
            rewardPointService,
            shipmentService,
            shippingService,
            shoppingCartService,
            stateProvinceService,
            storeService,
            taxService,
            vendorService,
            webHelper,
            workContext,
            workflowMessageService,
            localizationSettings,
            orderSettings,
            paymentSettings,
            rewardPointsSettings,
            shippingSettings,
            taxSettings)
        {
            _currencySettings = currencySettings;
            _addressService = addressService;
            _affiliateService = affiliateService;
            _checkoutAttributeFormatter = checkoutAttributeFormatter;
            _countryService = countryService;
            _currencyService = currencyService;
            _customerActivityService = customerActivityService;
            _customerService = customerService;
            _customNumberFormatter = customNumberFormatter;
            _discountService = discountService;
            _encryptionService = encryptionService;
            _eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
            _genericAttributeService = genericAttributeService;
            _giftCardService = giftCardService;
            _languageService = languageService;
            _localizationService = localizationService;
            _logger = logger;
            _orderService = orderService;
            _orderTotalCalculationService = orderTotalCalculationService;
            _paymentPluginManager = paymentPluginManager;
            _paymentService = paymentService;
            _pdfService = pdfService;
            _priceCalculationService = priceCalculationService;
            _priceFormatter = priceFormatter;
            _productAttributeFormatter = productAttributeFormatter;
            _productAttributeParser = productAttributeParser;
            _productService = productService;
            _returnRequestService = returnRequestService;
            _rewardPointService = rewardPointService;
            _shipmentService = shipmentService;
            _shippingService = shippingService;
            _shoppingCartService = shoppingCartService;
            _stateProvinceService = stateProvinceService;
            _storeService = storeService;
            _taxService = taxService;
            _vendorService = vendorService;
            _webHelper = webHelper;
            _workContext = workContext;
            _workflowMessageService = workflowMessageService;
            _localizationSettings = localizationSettings;
            _orderSettings = orderSettings;
            _paymentSettings = paymentSettings;
            _rewardPointsSettings = rewardPointsSettings;
            _shippingSettings = shippingSettings;
            _taxSettings = taxSettings;
        }

        #endregion


        #region Methods
        public override async Task<PlaceOrderResult> PlaceOrderAsync(ProcessPaymentRequest processPaymentRequest)
        {
            if (processPaymentRequest == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(processPaymentRequest));

            var result = new PlaceOrderResult();
            try
            {
                if (processPaymentRequest.OrderGuid == Guid.Empty)
                    throw new Exception("Order GUID is not generated");

                //prepare order details
                var details = await PreparePlaceOrderDetailsAsync(processPaymentRequest);

                var processPaymentResult = await GetProcessPaymentResultAsync(processPaymentRequest, details);

                if (processPaymentResult == null)
                    throw new NopException("processPaymentResult is not available");

                if (processPaymentResult.Success)
                {
                    var order = await SaveOrderDetailsAsync(processPaymentRequest, processPaymentResult, details);
                    result.PlacedOrder = order;

                    //move shopping cart items to order items
                    await MoveShoppingCartItemsToOrderItemsAsync(details, order);

                    //discount usage history
                    await SaveDiscountUsageHistoryAsync(details, order);

                    //gift card usage history
                    await SaveGiftCardUsageHistoryAsync(details, order);

                    //recurring orders
                    if (details.IsRecurringShoppingCart)
                        await CreateFirstRecurringPaymentAsync(processPaymentRequest, order);

                    //notifications
                    await SendNotificationsAndSaveNotesAsync(order);

                    //reset checkout data
                    await _customerService.ResetCheckoutDataAsync(details.Customer, processPaymentRequest.StoreId, clearCouponCodes: true, clearCheckoutAttributes: true);
                    await _customerActivityService.InsertActivityAsync("PublicStore.PlaceOrder",
                        string.Format(await _localizationService.GetResourceAsync("ActivityLog.PublicStore.PlaceOrder"), order.Id), order);

                    //raise event       
                    await _eventPublisher.PublishAsync(new OrderPlacedEvent(order));

                    //check order status
                    await CheckOrderStatusAsync(order);

                    if (order.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
                        await ProcessOrderPaidAsync(order);
                }
                else
                    foreach (var paymentError in processPaymentResult.Errors)
                        result.AddError(string.Format(await _localizationService.GetResourceAsync("Checkout.PaymentError"), paymentError));
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                await _logger.ErrorAsync(exc.Message, exc);
                result.AddError(exc.Message);
            }

            if (result.Success)
                return result;

            //log errors
            var logError = result.Errors.Aggregate("Error while placing order. ",
                (current, next) => $"{current}Error {result.Errors.IndexOf(next) + 1}: {next}. ");
            var customer = await _customerService.GetCustomerByIdAsync(processPaymentRequest.CustomerId);
            await _logger.ErrorAsync(logError, customer: customer);

            return result;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Then the DI for the custom service at startup.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
using Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Services;
using Nop.Services.Messages;
using Nop.Services.Orders;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Infrastructure.Extensions;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Infrastructure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents object for the configuring services on application startup
    /// </summary>
    public class NopStartup : INopStartup
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Add and configure any of the middleware
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">Collection of service descriptors</param>
        /// <param name="configuration">Configuration of the application</param>
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {


            //override services
            services.AddScoped<IOrderProcessingService, CustomOrderProcessingService>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure the using of added middleware
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="application">Builder for configuring an application's request pipeline</param>
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets order of this startup configuration implementation
        /// </summary>
        public int Order => 2001;
    }
}
```

It should work for 4.6, 4.5 and 4.4 of nopCommerce version. Tested for 4.6